# Difference between Aren't and Don't

Tags: questions, interrogatives

Could someone please clarify my doubt on below questions.

1. Aren't you on leave today?
2. Don't you on leave today?

Which one should I use to ask question.

Thanks

Comment: "Aren't you on leave today?" *Leave* here is a noun and you can consider the phrase  "on leave" used as as if it were an adjective, so you have to use *be*. "I am on leave", "I am absent", "I am happy"... I expect you are confused with the verb *leave* which means "go away" (among other meanings...) but you would not have *on* in front of a verb. "Don't you leave today?" means "Don't you go today?"

Comment: We say "I am on leave" and not "I do on leave", which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't = do not
Aren't = are not

'Do' means to perform an action. You *do* [an action].

'Are' is a form of the verb *to be*. There are so many different uses of this common verb it would be impossible to explain it entirely in a sentence. I'm hoping you already understand it. Generally speaking, *to be* refers to an existence, a state or a condition. You can *be* in a place; or you can *be* in a particular emotional state, for example.

These two contractions are built from completely different verbs and so are not interchangeable.

"On leave" is a state of being on approved leave from one's work. The correct expression would be "*aren't you on leave?*" (or "*are you not on leave?*")

Comment: Thanks for explaining clearly